# GraphQLError: Cannot query field "category" on type "ProductMarkdown"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using gatsby, and everything was working just fine yesterday, I get on today and try to start up my server and I get a big error in the console. I'm not totally sure where to look as I said yesterday it was literally working just fine.

```
⠁ [ { GraphQLError: Cannot query field "category" on type "ProductMarkdown".
    at Object.Field (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/FieldsOnCorrectType.js:65:31)
    at Object.enter (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:295:29)
    at Object.enter (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:337:25)
    at visit (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/language/visitor.js:227:26)
    at visitUsingRules (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:75:22)
    at validate (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:60:10)
    at /Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js:69:51
    at Promise._execute (/Users/taustin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:303:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/Users/taustin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
    at new Promise (/Users/taustin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)
    at graphqlImpl (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js:59:10)
    at graphql (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/graphql/graphql.js:48:227)
    at graphqlRunner (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/gatsby/dist/bootstrap/index.js:368:22)
    at _callee$ (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-product-markdown-pages/gatsby-node.js:32:14)
    at tryCatch (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:35:14
    at new Promise (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:164:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:14:12)
    at Object.createPages (/Users/taustin/Escalade/canopy-weights/node_modules/gatsby-plugin-product-markdown-pages/gatsby-node.js:95:15)
    message: 'Cannot query field "category" on type "ProductMarkdown".',
    locations: [ [Object] ],
    path: undefined } ]
```

I am getting the error above and from looking through all my files there is only one place that I call `productMarkdown`. What is confusing me is that there is no category to be found. I am not sure what is going on. This error happens when I run `gatsby develop`.

Here is the query:

```
productMarkdown(productId: { eq: $upperId }) {
      body
      title
      id
      titleDesc
      productInfo
      price
      active
      mainId
      cartParams {
        title
        options
      }
      extra {
        id
        title
      }
      specs {
        amount
        dimensions
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had exactly the same issue, couldn't find anything wrong and double checking contentful and the query using: http://localhost:8000/___graphql

I fixed it by installing gatsby again, `yarn add gatsby` which updated the following packages:

success Saved 6 new dependencies.

├─ gatsby-cli@2.4.1
├─ gatsby-link@2.0.2
├─ gatsby-plugin-page-creator@2.0.0
├─ gatsby-react-router-scroll@2.0.0
├─ gatsby@2.0.9
└─ graphql-skip-limit@2.0.0

Ran `gatsby develop` and field is now pulled through fine again with exactly the same code / query as before. Give a fresh npm / yarn install a go and see if that helps.